# Extract month name from datetime column or index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

i have a df

```
Name Date
A    2021-04-21
B    2021-03-21
C    2021-02-23
D    2021-03-22
```

and the dtype of Date is object

i want another column as

```
Name Date         Month
A    2021-04-21   April
B    2021-03-21   March
C    2021-02-23   February
D    2021-03-22   January
```

Tried with

```
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
```

this is giving the number of the month but not the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [`DatetimeIndex.month_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month_name.html)

```
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month_name()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%B')
print(df)

# Output
  Name        Date     Month
0    A  2021-04-21     April
1    B  2021-03-21     March
2    C  2021-02-23  February
3    D  2021-03-22     March
```

Or [`dt.month_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month_name.html):

```
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.month_name()
print(df)

# Output
  Name        Date     Month
0    A  2021-04-21     April
1    B  2021-03-21     March
2    C  2021-02-23  February
3    D  2021-03-22     March
```

Note: take care of your `locale` if you use `dt.strftime`.